# Distributing tasks with equal load in a multinode cluster

Tags: caching, locking, microservices, distributed-system

Spring scheduler is been triggered every one hour and the scheduler will be triggered from all the nodes deployed.
The scheduler reads a list of data from DB and does the process for each data in the list..

The processing of the data should not be duplicated across multiple nodes.
Each node should be able to uniquely identify the data in the list that it can process.

Is there any microservice pattern/distributed architecture pattern to achieve the same using distributed cache.

Please note:-
Would not be able to acquire lock on DB.
Each data in the list will have a unique id.